# Python - unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'

Tags: python, numpy

long time reader yet first time poster. I'm trying to write a simple user inputed sine graph drawer which affects the frequency, amplitude and phase shift of the graph. The aim is for everything to be in terms of pi to introduce Maths and Physics students to radians.

My problem is, I am getting the error in the title whilst trying to detect if the word 'pi' is in a user input and convert it to np.pi to use as a float. The code for the program (working other than this pi section) is posted below:

```
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = float(input("Amplitude of the curve: "))
f = float(input("Frequency of the curve: "))
p = input("Phase shift of the curve: ")

if "pi" in p:
str.translate(np.pi, "pi")
float(p)

else: float(p)

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
y = a*np.sin((f*x)+p)

plt.grid()

plt.xlabel('x = angle(rads)', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('y = amplitude', fontsize=18)
plt.title('The Sine Function', fontsize=26)

plt.xticks(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,5), ['0', '$\pi$/2', '$\pi$', '3$\pi$/2', '2$\pi$'])
plt.yticks(np.arange(min(y), max(y)+1, max(y)), [round(min(y)), '0', round(max(y))])

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

savefile = input("Do you wish to save the file? ")

if "no" in savefile:
sys.exit()

elif "yes" in savefile:
plt.grid()
plt.xticks(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,5), ['0', '$\pi$/2', '$\pi$', '3$\pi$/2', '2$\pi$'])
plt.yticks(np.arange(min(y), max(y)+1, max(y)), [round(min(y)), '0', round(max(y))])
plt.plot(x, y)
filename = input("Name the file: ")
plt.savefig(filename, format='pdf', bbox_inches='tight',     pad_inches=0.3)

else: print("\n","Invalid input. Ending Script" ,sep="", end="\n \n")
sys.exit()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: just adding the error traceback  would  help more

Comment: First time posting so I'm kind of new to how stack overflow does things. Very professional on here :)

Answer (score 1):

Your error is because of the following line :

```
y = a*np.sin((f*x)+p)
```

its because of that you doesn't convert `p` to float . in following command (**also you have a bad indentation you need to correct it**):

```
if "pi" in p:
    str.translate(np.pi, "pi")
    float(p)
```

the `float` function is not and in-place function you need to assign it to `p` again :

```
if "pi" in p:
    str.translate(np.pi, "pi")
    p=float(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, as @Kasra noted, calling

```
float(p)
```

doesn't modify the object `p`.  Instead, it returns a new float object.  Therefore, you need to save a reference to what it returns, e.g.:

```
p = float(p)
```

However, `str.translate(np.pi, "pi")` doesn't do what you think.  In fact, you should be getting an error when you call this.  `translate` is a method of string objects that used to replace particular characters with other particular characters.  You can't use it to replace the sub-string `"pi"` with the floating point object `np.pi` because a string can't contain floats.

What you're wanting is probably more like:

```
if 'pi' in p:
    p = p.replace('pi', '')
    p = np.pi * float(p)
else:
    p = float(p)
```

---

Also, you could simplify your matplotlib portion of things by hanging on to the figure object and saving it instead of creating a new figure.

For example (I'm running python 2.x, so I've made some minor changes.  The only differences are `raw_input` vs `input` and the `from __future__ import print_function`.):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = float(raw_input("Amplitude of the curve: "))
f = float(raw_input("Frequency of the curve: "))
p = raw_input("Phase shift of the curve: ")

if "pi" in p:
    p = np.pi * float(p.replace('pi', ''))
else:
    p = float(p)

x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
y = a*np.sin((f*x)+p)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.grid()
ax.set_xlabel('x = angle(rads)', fontsize=18)
ax.set_ylabel('y = amplitude', fontsize=18)
ax.set_title('The Sine Function', fontsize=26)

ax.set(xticks=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,5),
       xticklabels=['0', '$\pi$/2', '$\pi$', '3$\pi$/2', '2$\pi$'],
       yticks=np.arange(min(y), max(y)+1, max(y)),
       yticklabels=[round(min(y)), '0', round(max(y))])

ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

savefile = raw_input("Do you wish to save the file? ")
if "no" in savefile:
    pass
elif "yes" in savefile:
    fig.savefig('filename.pdf', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.3)
else:
    print("\nInvalid input. Ending Script\n\n")
```

Comment: Great idea on the sub plot to save the fig state. Saves a lot of unneeded code.

However, I am still receiving an error after typing in the word 'pi' into the p input when using these ideas. Even if I copy and paste your code and remove all the python 2 text, I receive the following message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jefferson/Desktop/test1.py", line 10, in <module>
    p = np.pi * float(p.replace('pi', ''))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: @Jefferson - What's happening is that you're trying to convert a blank string to a float.  The code I wrote assumes that you'd write `"1 pi"` or `"1pi"` instead.  If you'd like to handle the case of `"pi"`, you'll need to special-case it.  (Note that it will quickly become easier to use a full parser for this.  E.g. `"3/4 pi"`, etc.)

Comment: @JoeKington I am assuming that the user will not know to insert a number before pi (the graph is in radians so there's a chance there will be a division of pi, a multiplication of pi, just pi or just a number) How would I go about using the special case (or the full parser if it will be easier and yield the same results)?

I also receive problems with the ax.grid and x/y ticks & labels, saying they're are of NoneType

Thank you for your quick reply